# PnP PowerShell - Get-PnPFile error checking if file exists

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, pnp

I'm trying to check if file already exists in a SPO document library using PnP PowerShell command.

This is part of my PowerShell script:

```
Try {
    #Get all Files from the source folder
    $SourceFilesColl = $SourceFolder.Files
    $SourceFolder.Context.Load($SourceFilesColl)
    $SourceFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()

    #Iterate through each file and copy
    Foreach($SourceFile in $SourceFilesColl)
    {
        #Get the source file
        $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($SourceFolder.Context, $SourceFile.ServerRelativeUrl)

        #Copy File to the Target location
        $TargetFileURL = $TargetFolder.ServerRelativeUrl+"/"+$SourceFile.Name
        Write-Host "Preparing checking file..."
        $checkFile = Get-PnPFile $TargetFileURL

        if($checkFile) {
            write-host "File already exists." -f Green
        }
        else 
        {
            write-host "File not exists." -f Red
            [COPY FILE CODE HERE...]
        }
 }
```

My code is working fine for first item of the `foreach` loop, but from the second iteration `Get-PnPFile` runs really slow (first time it takes 1-2 seconds to run, second time it takes about 5 minutes and it seems freezed) and at the end it return that "File not exists" even if the file exists.

I've already checked PnP PowerShell releases and I have installed the latest.

I've also checked `$TargetFileURL` but it has not special chars or something that could break the script. For example this is similar to the content of  `$TargetFileURL` variable:

```
1st: "/sites/intranet/docs/my document.docx"
2nd: "/sites/intranet/docs/tech document.doc"
```

The only big difference is the file extension. Both filenames contains white spaces.
I've also tried with the `-ThrowExceptionIfFileNotFound` parameter in `Get-PnPFile` command (obviously I put it in a try-catch block), but nothing changed.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I tested the same file name and extension in my side and it's working as expected:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT6Iz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT6Iz.png) can you please try to create a new library and test if the issue still existed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$checkFile = Get-PnPFile $TargetFileURL **-AsListItem**
```